# C++ std::string to Ruby VALUE

Tags: c++, ruby, ruby-1.9.3, ruby-c-extension

How can I convert a C++ `std::string` object into a Ruby `VALUE` object?

I tried `rb_str_new2(c_string)`, but it did not work.

I have a function

```
VALUE foo(){return rb_str_new2(c_string);};
```

and that gives an error message:

```
cannot convert ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘size_t strlen(const char*)’
```

Comment: How did it not work? What's your code?

Comment: rb_str_new2(string_object.c_str()); should do the job easy.

Comment: Why do you call your variable `c_string`, if it's not a C string? oO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing [`std::string`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) to the function, but it expects a null-terminated `const char *`.

The [`std::string::c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) member function can be used to get one:

```
rb_str_new_cstr(string.c_str());
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and `rb_str_new2`? Can't find much intel about `rb_str_new_cstr`

Comment: @NiklasB, [they are the same function](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/README.EXT#L179). I prefer `rb_str_new_cstr` because I can infer that the function takes a C string as parameter.

Comment: Yes, I thought it might just be a more descriptive alias. Thanks, good to know, will use this in the future :)

Comment: @MatheusMoreira Ruby strings and C++ strings can contain zeros. So I would suggest rb_str_new( string.data(), string.size() )